# How do I set up a searchable email distribution list, accesible via webpage?

Tags: email, exchange-server

I work for a large company, which uses MS Exchange for Email.  We have a distribution list for people to post questions, where anyone can answer.  I am looking for a way to maintain a copy of this distribution list so that anyone can search it.  Ideally, this would be searchable from within Outlook as well as by going to a webpage, but I will take either one.  Someone has proposed to create a dummy email account, which just gets the distribution list traffic.  Everyone interested in this distribution list could then attach this account.  While this may work, there are several challenges with this approach:
1)  It becomes problematic when you have several hundred people attaching a single email Inbox/account.
2). I need this account to be read-only, so someone doesn't accidentally delete an email from this account, thinking that it is in their personal account.
3).  Our company has an auto-archive policy. This account would need to be exempt from that policy.

Any ideas?
Thanks
GS

Answer (score 0):

The dummy mailbox is not a bad idea. You can give the people appropiate permissions to the Inbox folder of that mailbox.

To work around the permission issue you could either

1) create a transport agent which monitors the mailflow and dumps all messages to a database or CMS/SharePoint/whatever.
2) Create the dummy mailbox and setup a service which monitors this mailbox using push/pull/streaming notifications and dump the messages to a database/CMS/SharePoint/whatever.

The SharePoint solution would make the search option a piece of cake. But if you don't already have a SharePoint instance up and running this might be overkill.